# FFMPEG / MJPEG кодек / Как добавить таблицы квантования (DQT) в avpacket->data?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Я пишу на с++ свой транскодер для преобразования любой картинки в jpeg основываясь на примерах в исходниках ffmpeg. я использую кодек MJPEG для создания jpeg картинки. Отправив AVFrame в MJPEG енкодер я получаю AVPacket. Затем я просто беру данные из структуры avpacket->data размером avpacket->size и сохраняю в файл с расширением jpg.
Проблема заключается в том что в готовой JPEG картинке имеется только одна DQT(Define Quantization Table). Насколько я понимаю в файле должно быть две таблицы.

Что мне необходимо сделать чтобы в avpacket->data было 2 таблицы квантования?

Comment: Используйте библиотеку для сохранения в формат jpeg, а не mjpeg видео энкодер.

Comment: @user7860670, интересный у вас совет... могли бы вы поподробнее раскрыть ваше решение?

Comment: Я имел ввиду взять libjpeg + libexif и сохранять в полноценный файл. А то, что выдают энкодеры в ffmpeg, обычно не годится для самостоятельного (то бишь без упаковки) воспроизведения.

Comment: @user7860670, я так понимаю вы предлагаете полностью отказаться от ffmpeg в пользу libjpeg + libexif?

Comment: для сохранения картинок - да

Comment: В добавок у меня задача шире, мне не нужно сохранять полученный jpeg на диск, а просто передать его в следующую часть моей программы.

Comment: libjpeg + libexif вполне могут работать с данными в памяти